# Show/Hide JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide

I have a problem where I have to show/hide multiple labels inside of the same td tag. Here is my JQuery code:

```
$j( document ).ready(function() {
    var records = [];
    var userID = 'here I am passing user ID'

    ~[tlist_sql;
        SELECT ID1, User_ID, ID2
        From RESERVATIONS
    ]
    records.push({'idOne':"~(ID1)",'idTwo':"~(User_ID)",'idThree':"~(ID2)"});
    [/tlist_sql]

    for(var i=0; i< records.length; i++){
      //here I am looking for matchin userID in my records array
      if(records[i].idTwo == userID){
        //If match, I want to hide input field and display name.
        $j('#hide_' + records[i].idOne).parent('.hideEmail').hide().next('.showName').show();
      }
      //Here I'm looking if any of my records idThree has value 0
      if(records[i].idThree == '0'){
        //if match hide input and show word 'Reserved' 
        $j('#hide_' + records[i].idOne).parent('.hideEmail').hide().next('.showResreved').show();
      }
    }
});
```

Here is my html code:

```
<td>
    <span class="hideEmail">
        <input type="text" value="" id="hide_~(ID1)"/>
    </span>
    <label class="showName" style="display:none">
        <span class="firstLast">Display Name</span>
    </label>
    <label class="showReserved" style="display:none">
        <span class="notavailable">Reserved</span>
    </label>
</td>
```

So problem show up once I combined both labels. At the first point I had only label with the class 'showName' and my logic worked fine. But once I added one more if statement in my JQuery and added another label with class 'showReserved' my code still displayed name label and class 'hideEmail' was hidden but class 'showReserved' never was displayed. Can anyone tell me why this does not work? Should I not combine two labels or something is wrong in my jquery?

Here is my working example: https://jsfiddle.net/dmilos89/nephebbv/2/

Comment: you have a typo: `.hide().next('showResreved')` should be `.hide().next('showReserved')`

Comment: Still does not work. My input filed is hidden but 'Reserved' never displayed.

Comment: You also are not escaping the `'` and there is no semicolon after `'here I'm passing user ID'`. Are you using an IDE of any sort?

Comment: That line is just a comment above the code.

Comment: That's not the way it appears in the question. You have not commented it out. In addition, you have other errors. For example `if(records[i].idTwo == UserID)`. There is no `UserID` anywhere in your code snippet. There is a `User_ID` and `userID` but no `UserID`. You are also comparing objects. Not comparing the string value of the `UserID`. I am not sure if this is pseudocode or not. Can you post the code that you said works? Or make a jsfiddle: www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Can you also state what framework/plugin you are using that allows you to put `~[tlist_sql;
        SELECT ID1, User_ID, ID2
        From RESERVATIONS
    ]` in your Javascript code?

Comment: That's a powerschool tag, and all those User_ID should be the same it's just my typo.

Comment: I posted jsfiddle so you can see in that example that my second label is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem its in this part:

```
$j('#hide_' + records[i].idOne).parent('.hideEmail').hide().next('.showResreved').show();
```

You typed "showReserved" wrong.

Here's a simple fix:

```
$j('#hide_' + records[i].idOne).parent('.hideEmail').hide().next('.showReserved').show();
```